# AngularFire show list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am retrieving some firebase db info in angular as below:

```
 this.items= this.db.list('/items/' + this.uId);
```

Then using the following, I can display the info:

```
<div class="text" *ngFor="let item of items| async">
   {{item.$value}}
</div>
```

Now, I am trying to display the value like below:

```
<p> {{(items| async)?. itemName}} </p>
```

But nothing shows in this approach. What am I doing wrong?

**ps.** Here is how I am pushing the info to db:

```
this.afDB.object('/items/' + this.uId).set({'itemName': item.displayname });
```

Comment: Looking at how you've written the data, `items` isn't going to have an `itemName` property; it will have a child with the value of `this.uId` that will have an `itemName` property.

Comment: i see. What change do you recommend? Thanks!